# ASP.NET Repeater DataItems

Tags: repeater

I have a simple repeater control with 5 columns and data that show up fine.  But, I have a 6th data item that I need to place in the next line after each of the table rows.

I have tried it placing the 6th item in the alternating template item, and it does what I want, but, does not loop through all the rows.

From the below code, the Notes data item is the one I want to appear in a new line after each row...The code below does it, but it does not loop through:

```
        <HeaderTemplate>
             <table class="tblMoves"  >
                <tr>
                    <th>
                        Type
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        ID
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        First Name
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        Last Name
                    </th>
                    <th>
                       Date
                    </th>
                </tr>

        </HeaderTemplate>
       <AlternatingItemTemplate>
         <tr>
         <td colspan="5">   <%#Eval("Notes")%></td>
         </tr>
         </AlternatingItemTemplate>
       <ItemTemplate>

        <tr>
        <td><asp:Label ID="empid" Text='<%#Eval("type") %>' runat="server"></asp:Label></td>
                    <td><asp:Label ID="Label1" Text='<%#Eval("ID") %>' runat="server"></asp:Label></td>

        <td><asp:Label ID="Label2" Text='<%#Eval("FirstName") %>' runat="server"></asp:Label></td>

        <td><asp:Label ID="Label3" Text='<%#Eval("LastName") %>' runat="server"></asp:Label></td>
        <td><asp:Label ID="Label4" Text='<%#Eval("Date", "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}") %>' runat="server"></asp:Label></td>
        </tr>
       </ItemTemplate>



         <FooterTemplate> </table></FooterTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add your notes row to your item template.

```
<ItemTemplate>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <asp:Label ID="empid" Text='<%#Eval("type") %>' runat="server"></asp:Label>
    </td>
    <td>
      <asp:Label ID="Label1" Text='<%#Eval("ID") %>' runat="server"></asp:Label>
    </td>
    <td>
      <asp:Label ID="Label2" Text='<%#Eval("FirstName") %>' runat="server"></asp:Label>
    </td>
    <td>
      <asp:Label ID="Label3" Text='<%#Eval("LastName") %>' runat="server"></asp:Label>
    </td>
    <td>
      <asp:Label ID="Label4" Text='<%#Eval("Date", "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}") %>' runat="server"></asp:Label>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="5"><%#Eval("Notes")%></td>
  </tr>
</ItemTemplate>
```

Comment: Thank you CM!  Worked perfectly.